# Request in C using openssl Not Returning Response

Tags: c, openssl

I've created a simple GET request using `openssl` and I'm having trouble on reading and returning the response. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define HOST "google.com"
#define PORT "443"

int main() {
  BIO* bio;
  SSL* ssl;
  SSL_CTX* ctx;

  SSL_library_init();
  
  ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
  if (ctx == NULL) {
    printf("CTX is null\n");
  }

  bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);
  BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, HOST ":" PORT);  
  
  if (BIO_do_connect(bio) <= 0) {
    printf("Failed connection\n");
    return 1;
  } else {
    printf("Connected\n");
  }
  
  char* write_buf = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n"
                    "HOST: google.com\r\n"
                    "\r\n";


  if (BIO_write(bio, write_buf, strlen(write_buf) <= 0)) {
    if (!BIO_should_retry(bio)) {
    
    }   
    printf("Failed write\n");
  }
  
  printf("%s", write_buf);
  int size;
  char buf[1024];
  
  for (;;) {
    size = BIO_read(bio, buf, 1023);
  
    if (size <= 0) {
      printf("No more data");
      break;
    }   
    buf[size] = 0;
    printf("%s\n", buf);
  }


  BIO_free_all(bio);
  SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
  return 0;
}
```

When I run this, the program is able to connect:

```
Connected                                                                       
GET / HTTP/1.0                                                                  
HOST: www.google.com
```

But it do not return any response, I have noted that the for loop for reading the response only takes one iteration, I don't know  what I am doing wrong, any suggestions for solving this issue?

Comment: Does program hang, or terminate without any data nor error? Looking at your output, it seems that program is stuck at BIO_read or keep running for loop without printing anything. Is that correct?

Comment: @MarkSouls exactly, I tried printing the iteration number and I only get one, there are no errors and the program terminates after a while (with no more iterations than the first one), the buffer doesn't have the response.

Comment: Are you sure you're running that code? The posted code says `HOST: google.com` but your output shows `HOST: www.google.com` which is different. If the running code also omits the last `"\r\n"` that would cause the server to not reply, just close after 4 min (in my testing).

Comment: Try adding the missing set of parens to your IF statement, if ( (BIO_write(bio, write_buf, strlen(write_buf)) <= 0)) , then we can work on fixing the 301 error

Comment: @JimCastro you are right, the issue was with the missing parenthesis.  Thanks!